# Transfer Data from one sheet to another and deleting old data in google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have 3 sheets.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jObb1jHIOV6LDXMrCHriSP2ywlOi9rDhwwNw5QYPcDk/edit#gid=2082210284

Audit: Filled via a google form and would be the master sheet
In Progress: Only Repair cars are inputted and would be accessed.
Completed: All Repair Cars that are completed.

If a car has been repaired, the in progress sheet would say "completed". Which should then remove this car from the In Progress and move it to the Completed. I have currently added a helper sheet which identifies the cells of the "completed value", edits it in the audit form and accordingly filters the value.

But I'm facing a few issues.

1. Google Script Error: Exception: This action would increase the number of cells in the workbook above the limit of 5000000 cells. removecompleted @ Code.gs:35
2. Automating the google script to run everytime the column D in Sheet "in Progress" is changed.

```
    function removecompleted() {
      var SHEET_NAME = "Audit";
      var SHEET_NAME_2 = "In Progress";
      var row_delete = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(5, 2).getValue();
      var row_update = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(6, 2).getValue();
      var col_delete = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(5, 3).getValue();
      var col_update = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(6, 3).getValue();
      if (row_delete !== 0) {
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME_2).getRange(row_delete, col_delete).clear();
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME).getRange(row_update, col_update).setValue("Completed");
       }
     }
```

Comment: Your sheet link is restricted, you haven't allowed access to it, please unrestrict.

Comment: Have done it, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The reason for the error:

These lines:

```js
  var row_delete = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(5, 2).getValue();
  var row_update = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(6, 2).getValue();
  var col_delete = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(5, 3).getValue();
  var col_update = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(6, 3).getValue();
```

End up with these values:

```js
row_delete = Wed Jun 02 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
row_update = Fri Jan 01 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
col_delete = 1452
col_update = 1531
```

The first two are Date objects.

In case you are not aware, `getRange()`, if you use it with two arguments, takes the row and then the column. So you are getting:

- B5
- B6
- C5
- C6

So when you use these values to `getRange()` again. You will get an error.

```js
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME_2).getRange(row_delete,col_delete).clear();
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME).getRange(row_update,col_update).setValue("Completed");
```

Specifically, since you are trying to give `getRange` a Date object, I believe it is being converted to a number, which will end up with `NaN` (Not a number) which sheets seems to interpret as being infinity. This is why you are getting the error:

```
This action would increase the number of cells in the workbook above the limit of 5000000 cells
```

I would recommend using `Logger.log()` or `console.log()` to debug your script to find out the variables contain the values you think they do.

```js
var row_delete = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(5, 2).getValue();
var row_update = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(6, 2).getValue();
var col_delete = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(5, 3).getValue();
var col_update = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(6, 3).getValue();
console.log(row_delete, row_update, col_delete, col_update)
```

#### How to make your script run when an edit is made

You can use an onEdit trigger, more information here:

> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers

#### Reference

- [getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column)
- [Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)